# React Correct usage of form onSubmit in a Parent Component for child input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to keep the state in my parent App Component and have functional stateless child components. The problem I'm running into is the onSubmit doesn't fire from the form component I'm calling. The onChange does work and I'm able to grab the value from the input. Also if I move the form out of the component, change the props to state and just use it in App the onSubmit works. I'm trying to understand why this is happening and how to pass input values between stateful and stateless components? This doesn't work:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = { 
  value: '',
  listItemValue: props.value || '',
  todoItems:  []
};
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
let value = event.target.value;
this.setState({
value: this.state.value,
listItemValue: value
});
}

handleSubmit(event) {
alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
event.preventDefault();
}

 render() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <TodoListForm name="todo"
                  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.listItemValue} />
    <TodoList />
  </div>
  );
 }
}
// Stateless Functional Component
const todoListForm = (props) => {
return (
        <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
            <label  htmlFor='todo-list-item'>Add a Todo</label> 
            <input  name={props.name}  
                    value={props.listItemValue} 
                    onChange={props.handleChange} 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder='Enter a todo ...'/>
            <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    className='TodoListForm__Button'>add</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

This does work(but I'm no longer using a todoListForm component for my Form:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = { 
  value: '',
  // listItemValue: props.value || '',
  todoItems:  []
};
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(event) {
alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
event.preventDefault();
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label  htmlFor='todo-list-item'>Add a Todo</label> 
        <input  name='todo'
                value={this.state.value} 
                onChange={this.handleChange} 
                type="text" 
                placeholder='Enter a todo ...'/>
        <button 
                type="submit" 
                className='TodoListForm__Button'>add</button>
    </form>
    <TodoList />
  </div>
 );
}
```

}

Comment: add `onSubmit={props.onSubmit}` in the stateless component having form tag.

Comment: Yes, I had thought that would work too but it still does not fire the handleSubmit  ...

Comment: There aren't any errors on the console ?

Comment: No errors. The only output is logging my props.  App is {}. TodoListForm{name: "todo", value: "", onSubmit: ƒ, handleChange: ƒ} The value does change on input...

Comment: `todoListForm` has small 't' while you're using capital 'T' while using it ?

Comment: Try `{onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}`

Comment: Ok, I just to rule it out I changed it to capital 'T' TodoListForm and onSubmit to {onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} - Still no errors and not firing...

Comment: I just made a Sandox of the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/jzwzl28yy. The `onSubmit` is triggering the `handleSubmit`. Changed the `handleChange` a bit.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I couldn't find the documentation for how to set up the onSubmit handler on the stateless side. That's why I originally left it off. I will always remember this now.